# How to fetch User activity from Audit Logs of OneDrive for Business

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, onedrive

I  have to get User Activity in SharePoint and OneDrive for Business. One way to get these information in reports through admin center -- https://blogs.office.com/2015/07/08/announcing-new-activity-logging-and-reporting-capabilities-for-office-365/ .
By admin credentials we can search reports and export it to local machine. But, I want to know, is there any other way to fetch these reports(using rest api or any other library)? Does Microsoft provide any other way to fetch  the user Activity from the Audit logs?
If someone can please help me to resolve these questions, it will be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneDrive for business is actually using sharepoint online. This is why there is no specific api for OneDrive. If you go in your browser and go to your OneDrive it should be Https:// yoursharepoint-my.sharepoint.com. So, you should be able to access the OneDrive audit logs using the api for sharepoint.

Comment: Thanks for reply..!!

Actually, I am facing another issue regarding audit logs. Whatever Action I have performed on portal, audit logs are not created for the same. Whenever I search for audit log files, I found no audit files. Any suggestion??? coz bydefault auditing is Enable.

Than you in advance.!

Comment: Shoot me an email at patrick.mcvay@meems.org so we can discuss this further.

Comment: Can you please let me know where I can get sharepoint audit log REST APIs (as mentioned above) at document level. 
I basically need to extract user activities around some excel sheets inside a folder in Sharepoint. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's the management activity API as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt227394.aspx

Here's the annoucement of that API from a year ago: https://blogs.office.com/2015/04/21/announcing-the-new-office-365-management-activity-api-for-security-and-compliance-monitoring/

This is basically an API that provides all the same information as what the admin portal provides and lets you discover the audit log data for items across SharePoint and OneDrive for Business.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

But, As per Management Activity API, They provide three content types till now. Those are-
-Audit.AzureActiveDirectory
-Audit.Exchange
-Audit.SharePoint

And my question is regarding get OneDrive for Business audit logs information.

Comment: Thanks for reply..!! Actually, I am facing another issue regarding audit logs. Whatever Action I have performed on portal, audit logs are not created for the same. Whenever I search for audit log files, I found no audit files. Any suggestion??? coz bydefault auditing is Enable. Than you in advance.!